# Using a BackSlash in Java

Tags: java, escaping, sequence, backslash

I want to print out a backslash. However, I get an error:

```
//Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
System.out.println("\");
```

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println("\\");`

`\` will escape  the second \ character.